verifying ledger typed message message hash by hand
when signing a typed message with a ledger nano, it displays a domain hash and a message hash as a way to verify the data you are signing. metamask shows me a json blob.
i cant seem to figure out the hashing being done so i can actually verify im signing on my ledger what metamask is showing me. so exactly what are the message and domain hashes displayed on the ledger and how can i verify them manually?
thanks
